# IOS HTTPCookie not recognized in PHP API

Tags: php, swift, api

I'm authenticating my users and then sending each of them a unique cookie which I will store server side and client side. In order to provide some level of security to my API, I'm sending every request to my api with that cookie.. I set the cookie on IOS like this

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey.originURL : apiURL, HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name : 
 cookie_name, HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value : cookie_value, HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path : "/"])

HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
```

I'm 100% sure that the way I'm setting my cookie up is perfect. I've done it in previous apps... just never with a PHP API on the other end. The only issue is that my PHP API doesn't recognize the cookie...

I'm checking like this:

```
if($_COOKIE['cookie_name'] != ''){ }
```

When I try to call the API from Postman (a google chrome extension that allows to pass cookies), it works fine and my php script recognizes the cookie. When I try to make calls from my mobile device, I get unauthorized access everytime because the PHP API fails to recognize that the cookie was passed...

The reason why I'm confident that I'm creating and passing my cookie correctly is because I do it in all of my Ruby on Rails app the same way...

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($_COOKIE);` and `var_dump($_REQUEST);`? (You can also use `print_r(...)`, but I personally prefer `var_dump` when I am developing.) Additionally, have you ran a proxy to sniff the app's communications and see what exactly is being sent?

Comment: @SpencerD thanks man! I'm going to try this asap and let you know how it goes. If that doesn't work, running a proxy sounds like something that could work to see what's going on. Know any good resources to learn how to do this?

Comment: @SpencerD both var dumping the cookies and requests return array(0) {} .. any advice?

Comment: Running a proxy just requires a debugging proxy application (I prefer Charles Debugging Proxy, but Fiddler can get the job done as well, and Fiddler is free). It's fairly straightforward, but you just need to run the proxy on a laptop or desktop connected to the same wifi access point as the phone, configure the phone's connection to use a proxy, and for the IP address and port, enter the local IP of the device running the proxy along with the port set in the application (I believe it is 8888 for both aforementioned tools). The program will act as a proxy server and log all the requests/resps.

Comment: @SpencerD Thanks for the informational response Spencer. Is there still value in doing this if the var_dump returned absolutely nothing? I checked the cookies on IOS and they're set properly... this is killing me lol

Comment: As for the var_dumps, that seems to indicate that PHP is not getting any information. I would first double check the code sending the request to make sure the shared cookie value is definitely being sent (which can also be confirmed with a debugging proxy) and if you are sure that it is, I would then look into your server configuration. (I doubt it is a server configuration issue if you are able to send the requests successfully with Postman, but it is possible I suppose.)

Comment: @SpencerD Got it. Will use fiddler and report back

Comment: @SpencerD man, I checked with fiddler and the mobile device is sending the cookie.... Postman works perfectly but php does not recognize it...

Answer (score 0):

Check like this

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey.originURL : apiURL, HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name : 
 cookie_name, HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value : cookie_value, HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path : "/"])

HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)


if($_COOKIE['cookie'] != ''){ }
```

the name of the cookie is not cookie name it's **cookie** as the line below

```
// (cookie) = cookie name
 HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
```

so this is how you should check

```
if($_COOKIE['cookie'] != ''){ }
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your reply. The cookie name is not cookie... cookie is just the variable name in ios. Trust me its not that im looking for the wrong name. Appreciate it though

Comment: Maybe you need to add some permission in the MANIFEST app file